# How to add commands to terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm a long time Windows user and how I usually do this in Windows is to edit the environment path and add the file path to the command that I want to use. Like when I want to use PHPUnit I just add this path to the environment variables:

```
tools/phpunit/vendor/bin/phpunit
```

And then I can just use `phpunit file_test.php` to run my tests. How do I do that in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the complete path of phpunit to `~/.bash_profile` like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:tools/phpunit/vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Thats it :)

**Make sure that you are adding the complete path of phpunit**. This is same as setting the environment variable PATH in Windows. `$PATH` will retain the values of PATH variable and we are just appending the location of phpunit to it.

**If the `~/.bash_profile` is not present you can add the line at the end of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: thanks! but where do I find this bash_profile?

Comment: Open a terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T. Type `gedit ~/.bash_profile`. In the editor which opens up, add that line, with the complete path to phpunit and save it.

Comment: For me it had to be path to `directory` not a `file`.

Comment: @heemayl your edit is badly formatted (`**` at the beginning of the last line), can you please fix it?

Comment: @A.L: I have added that line as a caveat..the `**` are not for **bold**-ing, those are there for indicating a note.

Comment: @thefourtheye: +1..nice answer.. :)

Comment: Will this work with zsh too? I tried to add vcpkg doing the same in ~/.zshrc and it does not seem to work. echo $PATH does have the file in the path. However entering command "vcpkg" throws an error.